# Lifetime problem removing from HashMap<UniCase<Cow<str>>, _>

Tags: rust, hashmap, lifetime

`UniCase` doesn't implement `Borrow`, which means that you can't index a map with `UniCase` keys without allocating a `String`. [Suggested workaround](https://github.com/seanmonstar/unicase/issues/22#issuecomment-808877130) is to use `HashMap<UniCase<Cow<str>>, _>`. Unfortunately, it doesn't always compile;

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::io::Result;

use unicase::UniCase;

fn rm_reader_keys<R: BufRead>(
    reader: R, dict: &mut HashMap<UniCase<Cow<str>>, String>
) -> Result<()> {
    for ln in reader.lines() {
        let line: String = ln?;
        if let Some((key, _)) = line.rsplit_once(' ') {
            dict.remove(&UniCase::unicode(Cow::Borrowed(key)));
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

produces

```
error[E0597]: `line` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:44:33
   |
40 |     reader: R, dict: &mut HashMap<UniCase<Cow<str>>, String>
   |                ---- has type `&mut HashMap<UniCase<Cow<'1, str>>, std::string::String>`
...
43 |         let line: String = ln?;
   |             ---- binding `line` declared here
44 |         if let Some((key, _)) = line.rsplit_once(' ') {
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
45 |             dict.remove(&UniCase::unicode(Cow::Borrowed(key)));
   |             -------------------------------------------------- argument requires that `line` is borrowed for `'1`
46 |         }
47 |     }
   |     - `line` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Why are you binding the value to `line` instead of using it directly in the scope you need it (in the if expression)?

Comment: `if let Some((key, _)) = ln?.rsplit_once(' ')` doesn't compile due to a borrow (`key`) from a temporary (`ln?`) that is destroyed at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. The problem is that the type has to be exactly the same, so we require the same lifetime as in the function's parameter. But it is generic and we have no way to get string living that long.

You can, however, use [`hashbrown`](https://docs.rs/hashbrown) directly. It has the [`Equivalent`](https://docs.rs/hashbrown/latest/hashbrown/trait.Equivalent.html) trait which is more general than `Borrow`:

```rust
use hashbrown::HashMap;

#[derive(Hash)]
struct UniCaseStrWrapper<'a>(UniCase<&'a str>);
impl hashbrown::Equivalent<UniCase<String>> for UniCaseStrWrapper<'_> {
    fn equivalent(&self, key: &UniCase<String>) -> bool {
        self.0 == *key
    }
}

fn rm_reader_keys<R: BufRead>(
    reader: R, dict: &mut HashMap<UniCase<String>, String>
) -> Result<()> {
    for ln in reader.lines() {
        let line: String = ln?;
        if let Some((key, _)) = line.rsplit_once(' ') {
            dict.remove(&UniCaseStrWrapper(UniCase::unicode(key)));
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```